# Use of "[adjective] in that ..."

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I think I have seen usages like below:

- The book is good in that it shows you the different options that might result from your choices.
- The media was clear in that they obviously despised the president.
- The suggested method is more effective than previous ones in that it requires less resources and achieves the result more quickly.

Is this *[adjective] + that ...* usage correct? Under which grammatical topic does it go if it is?

Comment: There's nothing special about *[adjective] in that*.  It's a normal use of "in that": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20that.

Comment: Please add actual linked examples. Are you sure you've got the second quote correct? The second example, using 'clear in that they' for 'clearly' is non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions for you, one for each of your sentences.

> The book is good in that it shows you the different options that might result from your choices

*Options* is probably not the right word, since options and choices are too close in meaning. "In that" is fine, but you save a word by substituting *because*.

> The media was clear in that they obviously despised the president.

Kind of wordy. Better would be "The media clearly despised the president."

> The suggested method is more effective than previous ones in that it requires less resources and achieves the result more quickly.

Again, "in that" could be substituted with *because*. *Fewer* should replace *less*. Also, for better parallelism, perhaps "it requires fewer resources and achieves quicker results" works well.